# Format for Data Input in MySQL Table

Tags: mysql

I have a question about format constraint for data that would be inputted into a MySQL table.

Here are the problem constraints:

- category_Name should allow up to 35 characters to be stored.
- shippingPerPound should be able to store digits in the format ##.##.
- offersAllowed should allow only ‘y’ and ‘n’ to be entered.

Here is my interpretation of the problem constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE category(
   category_Name VARCHAR(35),
   shippingPerPound INT(4),
   offersAllowed ENUM('Y','N') NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT categoryName_pk PRIMARY KEY(category_Name));
```

Specifically my question is about the shippingPerPound and how you make sure the format is "##.##". I feel like my interpritation is incorrect for shippingPerPound is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a decimal field instead of an `int(4)`, `DECIMAL(4,2)`

```
CREATE TABLE category(
    category_Name VARCHAR(35),
    shippingPerPound DECIMAL(4,2),
    offersAllowed ENUM('Y','N') NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT categoryName_pk PRIMARY KEY(category_Name)
);
```

That column will be able to store any value with 4 digits and two decimals.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html